# Accidentally reviewed close vote twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

In the process of reviewing the below, I got my browser tabs muddled, and managed to review a close vote for a second time:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1503735

[image: Close Votes Titsup]

The second vote was indended for another review, but I ended up coming back to the wrong tab after checking out the full duplicate question.

I assume I must have already had two tabs open on the first review in order to have one set in the state where I was able to select to leave open.

Obviously I made the mistake with the tabs, but the review function should probably have refused to register the second vote.

Comment: Well, user can review same post in more than one queue e.g. both in "close" and "low quality" queues. So probably server side validation isn't so simple. Won't be surprised if it's by design! :)

Comment: Worth to mention: for suggested edits there is server side validation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEHPo.png

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: ... `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE ReviewId = '1503735' AND UserId = '592111'` ? Each post has a different ID in each queue, so it shouldn't be too hard?

Comment: @Matt oh didn't know each post has different ID in each queue. Well, I stand corrected. Most likely it was overlooked.

Comment: Interesting that both reviews have a different result.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: That's cos the second "Leave Open" vote was for a different answer (see all the stuff about wrong tab etc). - I was leaving open a different post entirely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed going forward. Thanks for the report.